# Problem in Plotting and Adding Surface in Plotly

Tags: r, charts, 3d, plotly, surface

I´m a R newbie and currently try to plot my data in a 3d chart with a surface. I tried using the package plotly, but fail to do it.

I´ve got a matrix d3 (see below), but in the plot (see link below), either z or x are equal to the data in the matrix. In the plot x is always equal 1 and z is a counting number.

What do I need to change in the code?

Is it maybe how I created the matrix?

```
d3 <- data.matrix(mydataframe[1:3])
View(d3)
         z         y         x
[1,] 75.33333 1566.6667 0.2727273 
[2,] 76.66667 1585.6667 0.2788845
[3,] 75.33333 1462.6667 0.2384615
[4,] 77.66667 1340.6667 0.2489796
[5,] 75.66667 1328.3333 0.3658537
[6,] 83.33333 1315.6667 0.3459716
[...] ...

plot_ly(z = ~d3) %>% add_surface()
```

Here is an example of my failed Plotly 3d plot
[image: plot1]

If someone has an idea on how to plot the 3 variables with a surface differently to the package plotly, I really would appreciated it.

This is an example of a 3d regression, I would like to present my data in the same colours
[image: plot2]

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z` should be a matrix. You can use `outer`, as follows:

```
x <- seq(0, 8, length.out=100)
y <- seq(0, 3, length.out=30)
z <- t(outer(x, y, FUN=function(x,y) 5/3*y + 4*exp(-(x-4)^2)))

library(plotly)
plot_ly(x=x, y=y, z=z) %>% 
  add_surface() %>%
  layout(
    scene = list(
      xaxis= list(title="X"),
      yaxis= list(title="Y"),
      aspectmode = 'manual', 
      aspectratio = list(x=1, y=1, z=.5)
    )
  )
```

[image]